# Getting previous month of last year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the previous month data but of the following year. So if it's `May 2022`, I want the data for `April 2021`.

Here is what I currently have, but it is showing the date for 12 entire months and not just 1. Any advice would be great.

```
AND b.invoice_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))                                 
AND b.invoice_date < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -11, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MS SQL Server?

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Troubleshooting 101 Tip: To understand the values the date functions are producing wrap them in a SELECT.  That'll quickly shows your end date has the wrong year (2022).   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d36fb05abdf95653bf6b08944543f0b7

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use variables

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, getdate()) - 13, 0)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @StartDate)

SELECT * FROM TABLE b
WHERE b.invoice_date >= @StartDate                         
AND b.invoice_date < @EndDate
```

Comment: Thank you. I never thought of doing it this way.

Comment: Hi @TriiKyPandas, if the answer was helpful - accept it. It will help other to get solution for the similar problem